# How can I display text on the screen using libGDX without it looking pixelated?

Tags: java, android, graphics, libgdx, 2d

I'm developing an androd app and I'm using both BitmapFont and GlyphLayout to display a text on the screen. But unfortunately when I call scale() to make it bigger, the text looks pixelated. It's all blurry and looks like it's been drawn with a super-old computer. How do I solve that problem?

Comment: Take a look at [Freetype](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype)

Comment: Two options I would put out.  First, change your texture scaling type with `Texture.setFilter()`, and try options like `TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear`.  Second, to make the scaling easier, you might want to look into DistanceFieldFonts.